# How to add the relative humidity percentage to molar mass of air?

Tags: atmospheric-science, air, humidity

The higher the relative humidity percentage, the higher the molar mass of air, right? So then how do I add the higher amount of water in the air to the molar mass of air?

For example, let's take a cubic meter of air, with the molar mass of air being 28,96 g/mol, with a relative humidity of 85 %. Surely the humidity has added to the molar mass of the air within that cubic meter? How do I calculate this?

Comment: https://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/density-air-d_680.html

Comment: Water vapor is less dense than air, so as mentioned by Ben51, humid air has a lower molar mass than dry air.

Answer (score 2):

Water weighs about 18 g/mol, which is less than 29, so adding water vapor to air actually *decreases* the density.  The amount that the density (or molar mass, if you like) decreases depends on the change in the *absolute* humidity--you can't calculate based on relative humidity alone without knowing the temperature.  If the temperature and relative humidity are known, you can determine the absolute humidity from the Clausius-Clapeyron relation.  Let's say your 85%-relative-humidity air is at about 20 degrees Celsius, and you find, from Clausius-Clapeyron, that this equates to an absolute humidity of 2% (this is roughly right--for the illustration purposes, I'm not bothering with precision). Then your sample consists of 98% dry air molecules (average molar mass 29) and 2% water molecules (molar mass 18). The molar mass of the combined sample is: $$29 \mathrm{g/mol} \times0.98+18\mathrm{g/mol}\times0.02=28.78\mathrm{g/mol}.$$

Comment: pilots know this too; on a humid day, the plane's wings produce less lift and the takeoff run for a given plane must be extended accordingly.

Comment: How does one use the Clausius-Clapeyron relation? Whereever I look it requires a lot more than just the relative humidity and temperature

Comment: @andrew To do it properly you need to numerically integrate the equation.  For rough estimates, there is a closed form solution if you approximate the latent heat of vaporization as constant with temperature.  Alternatively, you can get approximate values off a plot, like [this](http://chemed.chem.purdue.edu/genchem/topicreview/bp/ch14/graphics/14_6fig.gif)

Comment: Can you show how to get that 2% figure?